# org-capture : how to choose the target file at the end of the process?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-capture a lot, it's a terrific feature.

However, sometimes i'd like to choose the target of the note during or at the end of the process, not at the beginning from the template.

The process I imagine (below I use the exact terms of the variable org-capture-template, in *italic*:

1. C-c c
2. choosing the *entry* for it's *template*, not caring for it's *target*
3. typing my note
4. C-c C-c refiles my note at the place I want

So far, my *org-capture-template* is :
`(("t" "Test" entry (file+headline "my/path/to/notes.org" "Entries to be refiled") (file "my/path/to/my-org-capture-template.org")))`

with org-capture-template.org :

```
* %?
:PROPERTIES:
:TARGET-FILE:
:TARGET-HEADLINE:
:END:
```

What I want is C-c C-c running a function inferring the target, file and headline, from the value of TARGET-FILE and TARGET-HEADLINE, and refiling my note accordingly.

Comment: You can do this interactively by ending with `C-c C-w` instead of `C-c C-c`.

Comment: ok, sorry if that was not clear, but I do not want to do that interactively. I want to do that automatically from the content of the not, eg :TARGET-FILE: and :TARGET-HEADLINE: values

Comment: What happens when two or more org files have the same headline -- how do you determine programmatically which file to insert the newly created capture entry -- and what happens if the user has duplicate headlines in the same file -- and what happens if none of the files have a matching headline -- it gets a little complicated to start searching and then adding prompts for the user to choose, bit is nevertheless doable.

Comment: I do **not** want to do that with prompts, but automatically from the contents of the note.

Comment: There are some situations where the computer will choose **incorrectly** if it is done entirely *automatically* without any prompts, and I have named just a few of those computer-confusing situations in the previous comment.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to choose where a captured entry will go.

You can always use `org-refile` (`C-c C-w`) in the capture buffer to move the capture.  This will also finalize the capture.

If you want to encode the target headline in the capture template, use `file+headline` as the target, thusly:

```
("t" "Todo" entry
  (file+headline "/path/to/file.org" "Target Headline")
  "* TODO %?"
)
```

Another solution is to use `file+function` as the target for your capture template.  First define a function that prompts for a headline and jumps to it.

```
(defun org-get-target-headline (&optional prompt)
  "Prompt for a location in an org file and jump to it.

This is for promping for refile targets when doing captures."
    (let* ((target (save-excursion
                     (org-refile-get-location prompt nil nil t)))
           (file (nth 1 target))
           (pos (nth 3 target))
           )
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
        (goto-char pos)
        (org-end-of-subtree)
        (org-return)
    )))
```

Then add a capture template using this function to get the target:

```
            '("t" "Todo" entry
              (file+function "/path/to/file.org" org-get-target-headline)
             "* TODO %?")
```

You will be prompted for the target before being dropped into the capture buffer.  This is most useful when the template has `:immediate-finish t` and you never get a capture buffer to refile from.

And that's not all! There are a number of other ways for a template to select it's target, see the manual for [org-capture-templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements) for a list of them.
The most general version is to use `function` as the target, which lets you give an arbitrary function for both the target file and headline.

EDIT:

As of `org-mode` 9 the above function no longer works.  Instead use

```
(defun org-get-target-headline (&optional targets prompt)
  "Prompt for a location in an org file and jump to it.

This is for promping for refile targets when doing captures.
Targets are selected from `org-refile-targets'. If TARGETS is
given it temporarily overrides `org-refile-targets'. PROMPT will
replace the default prompt message.

If CAPTURE-LOC is is given, capture to that location instead of
prompting."
  (let ((org-refile-targets (or targets org-refile-targets))
        (prompt (or prompt "Capture Location")))
      (org-refile t nil nil prompt)))
```

which does the same thing, but also allows you to restrict the set of possible targets.

Comment: As answered above, I should have made it clear : for what I want to do, C-c C-w is not an option. The other solutions doesn't either fulfill the requirement : I want to automatically (not interactively) refile, at the end of the process, from the contents of the note, eg from :TARGET-FILE: and :TARGET-HEADLINE: values that I would have defined in the note.

Comment: thx. the function gives me an error:  ``save-excursion: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 3), 4Invalid face reference: quote``. any clue?

Comment: I haven't seen the Invalid face error, but I do get the a Wrong number of arguments error.  This must have stopped working with some `org-mode` upgrade.  I have a version that works in Org 9 that I'll edit in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any simple way to do what want here.

To run something after your note has been captured, you could try using the `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`. At that point you may be able to do something like this:

- jump to the last captured note (`org-capture-goto-last-stored`)
- parse the org element for your custom target information
- call `org-refile` and pass a custom refile location (`RFLOC`) based on what you've read from the note

Comment: Instead of using `org-capture-after-finalize-hook` and jumping to the last capture, maybe use `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` instead?  The capture buffer is still around and widened when before-finalize runs.

Comment: That makes sense - save a step.