# Select subheading for capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Unfortunately, I am not very proficient in writing my own lisp functions.  I want to create a capture template that prompts for a sub-heading of a particular heading as the capture location. E.g. for

```
* heading 1
** subheading 1.1
** subheading 1.2
* heading 2
** subheading 2.1
** subheading 2.2
```

I want the template

```
(setq org-capture-templates
 '(("t" "todo" entry (file+function "~/org/org.org" function-i-need)
            "**** TODO %^{Brief Description} %^g\n%?\n")
   )
```

)

To offer targets under `subheading 2` only.

Would be great if someone could help me out with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org-capture : how to choose the target file at the end of the process?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/org-capture-how-to-choose-the-target-file-at-the-end-of-the-process)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5923/2710 has solutions that provide such a function.