# Custom org-capture find headerline function error, wrong number of arguments

Tags: org-mode, emacsclient, org-capture, doom, org-refile

So, I managed to get my [headline retrieval function fixed](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71093/37666), so now the function searches and finds my header lines, but when I select the one I want to use..  it oddly throws back this `apply: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 4` error. I am using Doom Emacs and org-mode v9.6 in Doom Emacs (showing in screenshot). Anyone know what's going on with the function?
Doom Version:

```
 doom version
> Executing 'doom version' with Emacs 27.2 at 2022-03-25 10:31:00
  GNU Emacs     v27.2            nil
  Doom core     v3.0.0-dev       HEAD -> master aed2972d 2022-03-22 02:49:09 +0100
  Doom modules  v22.03.0-dev     HEAD -> master aed2972d 2022-03-22 02:49:09 +0100
```

[image: Org Version on Doom Emacs]
I'm using `doom upgrade` to upgrade the packages and Doom Emacs, I'm unsure where Doom Emacs is getting the updates, I just know that running `doom upgrade` updates itself and the packages.

The function + org template

```
        ("aa" "Assignments" entry
                (file+function "~/sync/org/Assignments.org" org-get-target-headline)
                "\n*TODO %? %<%I:%M %p> - n"
                ;; ,(dw/read-file-as-string "~/Notes/Templates/Daily.org")
                :clock-in :clock-resume
                :empty-lines 1)
....

(defun org-get-target-headline (&optional targets prompt)
  "Prompt for a location in an org file and jump to it.

This is for prompting for refile targets when doing captures.
Targets are selected from `org-refile-targets'. If TARGETS is
given it temporarily overrides `org-refile-targets'. PROMPT will
replace the default prompt message.

If CAPTURE-LOC is is given, capture to that location instead of
prompting."
  (let ((org-refile-targets (or targets org-refile-targets))
        (prompt (or prompt "Capture Location")))
    (org-refile t nil nil prompt)))
```

Error from Emacs Debugger:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 0) 4)
  org-save-all-org-buffers(t nil nil "Capture Location")
  apply(org-save-all-org-buffers (t nil nil "Capture Location"))
  org-refile(t nil nil "Capture Location")
  (let ((org-refile-targets (or targets org-refile-targets)) (prompt (or prompt "Capture Location"))) (org-refile t nil nil prompt))
  org-get-target-headline()
  org-capture-set-target-location(nil)
  #f(compiled-function (&optional goto keys) "Capture something.\n\\<org-capture-mode-map>\nThis will let you select a template from `org-capture-templates', and\nthen file the newly captured information.  The text is immediately\ninserted at the target location, and an indirect buffer is shown where\nyou can edit it.  Pressing `\\[org-capture-finalize]' brings you back to the previous\nstate of Emacs, so that you can continue your work.\n\nWhen called interactively with a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument GOTO, don't\ncapture anything, just go to the file/headline where the selected\ntemplate stores its notes.\n\nWith a `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]' prefix argument, go to the last note stored.\n\nWhen called with a `C-0' (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.\n\nWhen called with a `C-1' (one) prefix, force prompting for a date when\na datetree entry is made.\n\nELisp programs can set KEYS to a string associated with a template\nin `org-capture-templates'.  In this case, interactive selection\nwill be bypassed.\n\nIf `org-capture-use-agenda-date' is non-nil, capturing from the\nagenda will use the date at point as the default date.  Then, a\n`C-1' prefix will tell the capture process to use the HH:MM time\nof the day at point (if any) or the current HH:MM time." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1567eda85bd5>)(nil)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (&optional goto keys) "Capture something.\n\\<org-capture-mode-map>\nThis will let you select a template from `org-capture-templates', and\nthen file the newly captured information.  The text is immediately\ninserted at the target location, and an indirect buffer is shown where\nyou can edit it.  Pressing `\\[org-capture-finalize]' brings you back to the previous\nstate of Emacs, so that you can continue your work.\n\nWhen called interactively with a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument GOTO, don't\ncapture anything, just go to the file/headline where the selected\ntemplate stores its notes.\n\nWith a `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]' prefix argument, go to the last note stored.\n\nWhen called with a `C-0' (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.\n\nWhen called with a `C-1' (one) prefix, force prompting for a date when\na datetree entry is made.\n\nELisp programs can set KEYS to a string associated with a template\nin `org-capture-templates'.  In this case, interactive selection\nwill be bypassed.\n\nIf `org-capture-use-agenda-date' is non-nil, capturing from the\nagenda will use the date at point as the default date.  Then, a\n`C-1' prefix will tell the capture process to use the HH:MM time\nof the day at point (if any) or the current HH:MM time." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1567eda85bd5>) nil)
  (let ((+file-templates-inhibit t)) (apply fn args))
  +file-templates-inhibit-in-org-capture-a(#f(compiled-function (&optional goto keys) "Capture something.\n\\<org-capture-mode-map>\nThis will let you select a template from `org-capture-templates', and\nthen file the newly captured information.  The text is immediately\ninserted at the target location, and an indirect buffer is shown where\nyou can edit it.  Pressing `\\[org-capture-finalize]' brings you back to the previous\nstate of Emacs, so that you can continue your work.\n\nWhen called interactively with a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument GOTO, don't\ncapture anything, just go to the file/headline where the selected\ntemplate stores its notes.\n\nWith a `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]' prefix argument, go to the last note stored.\n\nWhen called with a `C-0' (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.\n\nWhen called with a `C-1' (one) prefix, force prompting for a date when\na datetree entry is made.\n\nELisp programs can set KEYS to a string associated with a template\nin `org-capture-templates'.  In this case, interactive selection\nwill be bypassed.\n\nIf `org-capture-use-agenda-date' is non-nil, capturing from the\nagenda will use the date at point as the default date.  Then, a\n`C-1' prefix will tell the capture process to use the HH:MM time\nof the day at point (if any) or the current HH:MM time." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1567eda85bd5>) nil)
  apply(+file-templates-inhibit-in-org-capture-a #f(compiled-function (&optional goto keys) "Capture something.\n\\<org-capture-mode-map>\nThis will let you select a template from `org-capture-templates', and\nthen file the newly captured information.  The text is immediately\ninserted at the target location, and an indirect buffer is shown where\nyou can edit it.  Pressing `\\[org-capture-finalize]' brings you back to the previous\nstate of Emacs, so that you can continue your work.\n\nWhen called interactively with a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix argument GOTO, don't\ncapture anything, just go to the file/headline where the selected\ntemplate stores its notes.\n\nWith a `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]' prefix argument, go to the last note stored.\n\nWhen called with a `C-0' (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.\n\nWhen called with a `C-1' (one) prefix, force prompting for a date when\na datetree entry is made.\n\nELisp programs can set KEYS to a string associated with a template\nin `org-capture-templates'.  In this case, interactive selection\nwill be bypassed.\n\nIf `org-capture-use-agenda-date' is non-nil, capturing from the\nagenda will use the date at point as the default date.  Then, a\n`C-1' prefix will tell the capture process to use the HH:MM time\nof the day at point (if any) or the current HH:MM time." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1567eda85bd5>) nil)
  org-capture(nil)
  #<subr funcall-interactively>(org-capture nil)
  apply(#<subr funcall-interactively> (org-capture nil))
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(org-capture record nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> (org-capture record nil))
  explain-pause--wrap-call-interactively(#<subr call-interactively> org-capture record nil)
  apply(explain-pause--wrap-call-interactively #<subr call-interactively> (org-capture record nil))
  call-interactively(org-capture record nil)
  command-execute(org-capture record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-capture" nil)
  #<subr funcall-interactively>(execute-extended-command nil "org-capture" nil)
  apply(#<subr funcall-interactively> (execute-extended-command nil "org-capture" nil))
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-capture" nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> (execute-extended-command nil nil))
  explain-pause--wrap-call-interactively(#<subr call-interactively> execute-extended-command nil nil)
  apply(explain-pause--wrap-call-interactively #<subr call-interactively> (execute-extended-command nil nil))
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Edit:
I took out the t variable and now the error is that `prompt` is a void.

```
(defun org-get-target-headline (&optional targets prompt)
  "Prompt for a location in an org file and jump to it.

This is for promping for refile targets when doing captures.
Targets are selected from `org-refile-targets'. If TARGETS is
given it temporarily overrides `org-refile-targets'. PROMPT will
replace the default prompt message.

If CAPTURE-LOC is is given, capture to that location instead of
prompting."
  (let ((org-refile-targets (or targets org-refile-targets))
        (prompt (or prompt "Capture Location")))
    (org-refile nil nil prompt)))
```

Comment: Somehow `org-save-all-org-buffers` gets called with the 4 arguments that were passed to `org-refile`. However, I can not find why because I can not find the `(apply org-save-all-org-buffers ...)` in the code base of org 9.5.2 (which is the version I am using). Maybe update your `org` first...

Comment: Still getting the same error in version 9.6, updating question with the screenshot of my version

Comment: Ah so there is version 9.6 already... Well, then I'm stuck here.  So then I would advise you to [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html)  the `org-refile` function (edebug is simple and powerful). Or maybe search/(rz)grep your code-base for `apply org-save-all-org-buffers`.

Comment: There isn't a 9.6 yet - I just updated from the git repo and I get `9.5.2 (release_9.5.2-409-gc5ea19)`. And as of 2022/03/24, I had not seen an announcement on the ML. Maybe the OP can tell us where/how they got the update.

Comment: @NickD I'm using Doom Emacs, I'm not sure where it's getting the updates from exactly. I just ran doom upgrade

Comment: Strange. Are you getting the version with `M-x org-version`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ran to get get Org's version

Comment: Doing `git describe e7ea951` in my clone of the upstream repo returns `release_9.5.2-364-ge7ea951ac976`, so a bit behind the current git HEAD but fairly recent. I wonder though if Doom adds its own special sauce.

Comment: @NickD I'm not sure if this is useful, but this is the packages.el for Doom Emac's org module https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/master/modules/lang/org/packages.el

Comment: Thanks! They seem to muck around with the version but if that's all they do, then there is no other difference that could have a bearing to this problem.

Comment: They also configure packages too, but idk how they affect how the variables. https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/master/modules/lang/org

Comment: Ok, so I took out the `t` out and now it's saying that `prompt` is a void. How else do I go and make this function work?